# Why I need to bring cream to almost boil for cream brulee?

Tags: creme-brulee

I want to try to create cream brulee for the first time. In all the recipes that I have seen till now, you normally need to bring cream to almost boil and let it cool for a little before slowly mixing with eggs. But I wonder is there any reason for heating cream first?

I should say that I gonna use vanilla extract. I can guess if I use vanilla pod, heating cream first with the pod helps to infuse vanilla better in the cream. But in case of vanilla extract, it will be not the case. Is there any other reason for heating cream before mixing with eggs? Can I just mix room-temp creme directly into eggs?

Comment: @Luciano thanks for link. :) practically it says some people do, some other don't... :)

Comment: The main takeaway seems to be: do it if you want to infuse more flavour using vanilla pods, but it's not entirely necessary if you're using an extract.

Comment: @Afshin the point is, if that's the answer which was given the first time the question was asked, the same answer is to be expected the second time you ask it. So we do close as a duplicate when the question exists before, even if you wish the answer had been different.

Comment: @rumtscho I know. I first searched for answer but I could not find it. That's why I asked. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to scold you for not having found the old question. It is not so easy, people frequently use different words to formulate the same thing, and the search function doesn't detect the old question. I was only trying to provide a justification why we are closing, and why leaving it open (which many new users wish) is unlikely to be useful for you in the end.